# How to hide an ImageView before next image is shown?

Tags: java, android

I am stuck at a point in making an application. I have images stored in hashmap and whatever line I give it as an input is broken into separate words on basis of space and its corresponding images are fetched.Images are shown one by one. What I want is that when one image is shown then before showing next image, the previous image should disappear. But being new to android, I am sort of not finding a way for it without click listeners.Is there any way of doing it in my regular for loop.

```
 Handler handler1 = new Handler();

                for (int s = 0; s < separated.length; s++) {

                    final int i = s;

                      handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViews[i]);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            100, 100);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            if(pol.map_a.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_a.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_b.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                        iv.setImageResource(pol.map_b.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                                     }
            else if(pol.map_c.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_c.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_d.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_d.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_e.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_e.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_f.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_f.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
 }


                        }, i * 500);
                    }
```

Comment: Use iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); then load your new photo and again set iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: i am writing iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  right after i * 500); in the end and writing iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  just when the public void run() starts .... but it doesn't work........ where am i going wrong can you point it out